# Dcast Issue: keep multiple matching rows when idvars are not unique

Tags: r, dcast

I have perused the existing posts on dcast and the official dcast vignette. I may not have framed my searches correctly, but I haven't found an example quite like mine. Take a look at my toy data on excel (which I can read into R). It's already in melted form. As you can see, the student~day columns have multiple duplicate entries because a student can wear multiple articles of clothing on the same day. I want to recast as wide without losing duplicate rows (see arnav's first two entries)--

| Student | Day | Clothes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Arnav | Mon | red shirt |
| Arnav | Mon | blue pants |
| Beth | Mon | dress |
| Chuo | Mon | dress |
| Beth | Tues | green shirt |
| Beth | Tues | blue pants |
| Chuo | Tues | dress |

For each student on each day, I want to combine the clothes' column like this:

| Student | Day | Clothes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Arnav | Mon | red shirt, blue pants |
| Beth | Mon | dress |
| Chuo | Mon | dress |
| Beth | Tues | green shirt, blue pants |
| Chuo | Tues | dress |

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The key is using the `unwrap_cols` function from the `unheadr` package. I thought there might be something in the `tidyr` package (opposite of the `separate_rows` function but couldn't find anything).

```
library(unheadr)
library(tidyverse)

clothes <- tibble(
  Student = c('Arnav', 'Arnav', 'Beth', 'Chuo', 'Beth', 'Beth', 'Chuo'), 
  Day = c('Mon', 'Mon', 'Mon', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Tues', 'Tues'),
  Clothes = c('red shirt', 'blue pants', 'dress', 'dress', 'green shirt', 'blue pants', 'dress')
)

clothes %>% 
  unite(StudentDay, Student:Day) %>%
  unwrap_cols(groupingVar = StudentDay, separator = ', ') %>%
  separate(StudentDay, into = c('Student', 'Day'))
```

Comment: unfortunately I got these errors + warnings (I am googling as we speak):

Error in unite(., StudentDay, Student:Day) : 
  lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/tidyr/R/tidyr.rdb' is corrupt

In addition: Warning messages:
1: In unite(., StudentDay, Student:Day) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In unite(., StudentDay, Student:Day) :
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1

Comment: That to me looks like you have an error in your loading of the `tidyr` package. You might want to reinstall that one (or `tidyverse` in general). I'm not able to reproduce that error message.

Comment: Yeah! Ultimately, I had to restart R and re-select tidyr and tidyverse from the packages window

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: yes it did, but after doing this and re-loading tidyr, my pipe character (%>%) no longer works. I am running the same lines that used to work before I implemented your solution. They used to run just fine, but now I'm getting the error, "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables"
I've looked at threads with this error, but they had something wrong with their data or the functions they wanted to pipe to. However, it used to work (ex: df %>% subset(.,.$Day=="Monday"). If I restart R and don't load tidyverse, the pipe works again

Comment: If your original question is answered then please accept the answer I posted. This latest comment sounds like a different problem that you're experiencing. If that's the case then feel free to post a new question so it can be solved separately.

Comment: No problem, but I wrote the comment because most users will have both libraries loaded and may experience similar problems